How to determine the first reliable position of the apple vision pro device
In my answer to this question, I outline how I track the Apple Vision Pro
device's position. Below I have annotated three locations in the code when I
can use worldInfo to query the device's position:
struct ImmersiveVisionAlignmentView: View {
    let session = ARKitSession()
    let worldInfo = WorldTrackingProvider()
    @State var sceneEvent : Cancellable? = nil
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            try? await session.run([worldInfo])
            (1)
            sceneEvent = content.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { event in
                (2)
            } as? any Cancellable
        } update: { content in
            (3)
        }
    }
}

In each of these locations I can query the position using code similar to this:
if let pose = worldInfo.queryDeviceAnchor(atTimestamp: CACurrentMediaTime()) {       
    let worldInfoState = worldInfo.state.description
    print("world tracking state = \(worldInfoState)")
    let toDeviceTransform = pose.originFromAnchorTransform
    let C = toDeviceTransform.translation // fetch last column of 4x4 matrix
    print("C = \(C)")
}

The code at these three locations are executed accordingly as follows:

Whenever the RealityView content is (re)created per SwiftUI rules
On every frame
On each "update" event

This first time I get a report is in (1):
world tracking state = running
C = SIMD3<Float>(-0.05999353, 0.029994667, -0.0010033477)

The second report is in update (3):
world tracking state = running
C = SIMD3<Float>(-0.05999353, 0.029994667, -0.0010033477)

The third thru the seventh report occurs on each frame callback (2)
world tracking state = running
frame : C = SIMD3<Float>(-0.05999353, 0.029994667, -0.0010033477)

Finally, on the eighth frame callback (2) I get the correct established
position (0, 1.627, 0) of the device:
world tracking state = running
C = SIMD3<Float>(-1.052022e-05, 1.6299946, -1.2180302e-05)

From this time forward, the positions are consistent
(BTW, this experiment was done on the vision os simulator, but mimics
the same issue that is on a real device).
So obviously it takes awhile for the tracking system to establish its initial position;
e.g. I imagine the IMU and visual odeemetry system have to find the floor, etc...
Question: How, or at what point, can I determine that the initial position of the device has been established?
The tracking system reports a "running" state
in each of these cases, but it takes awhile before it establishes its initial
coordinate system. Of course I could wait for some "artificial delay time" (e.g.,
after 1000 frame callbacks) before I query the position or look for a discontinuity
in position, but this is not a very satisfying solution.
